# Нужно рассчитать количество денег(,) необходимое, чтобы сделать проект

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Нужна запятая?

> Нужно рассчитать количество денег(,) необходимое, чтобы сделать проект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Нужно рассчитать количество денег, **необходимое, чтобы сделать проект.***

Нет никаких оснований не ставить запятую.

См.: [Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Согласен полностью, плюс ставлю.

Comment: @Максим Спасибо!

Comment: Ответ верный, но стилистика вопроса нехороша. Предложение должно делиться на две части, а как это сделать. Информативность сообщения низкая, много ненужных слов. Нужно менять структуру предложения.

Comment: Например: Нужно рассчитать количество денег, необходимое для завершения проекта. Тогда и о запятой не надо будет спрашивать.

Comment: @Sharon Пусть нехороша. Но предложение делится на две части, пауза перед "чтобы" минимальная, запятая перед союзом чисто грамматическая. Ненужных слов не много. Вы и не такие предложения пропускали, и даже одобряли :))

Comment: Не получится разделить))  Это такое особенное предложение, которое никак пополам не делится.  ДИАЛОГ. – Нужно рассчитать количество денег.  –  Какое количество? –   // Необходимое, чтобы сделать проект! //  Ну кто так говорит?

Comment: @Sharon Ну вот вы же разделили, поставив точку. Второе предложение очень легко читается без паузы.

Comment: Легко! Если это отдельное предложение: НеобходИмое, / чтобы сделать проЕкт!    Любое предложение делится пополам (тема и рема). Поэтому точку обязательно поставьте))  А если мы будем пропускать такую стилистику, у нас будет много-много таких предложений.

Comment: Отдельное предложение, да, лучше читается пополам, и то его можно прочитать, а тем более сказать без паузы. В более распространённом ещё больше вероятности произнести без паузы. // Но мы уже очень отвлеклись от темы. Спасибо за замечания!

Comment: Пожалуйста за замечание. Голос от меня, заодно и Лео-мастера поблагодарю, а то вы забыли это сделать. Пусть и дальше пишет, тут места много.