# Нужно ли обособлять определение в постпозиции, в состав которого входит придаточное?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Вот **предложение**:

*Он сказал это с **видом(,) достаточно уверенным**, чтобы кто-то стал ему возражать.*

1. Определение стоит **после** определяемого слова, при этом в его состав входит **придаточное** предложение. **Интонационно** оно не обособляется, но нужно ли его обособлять **по грамматике?** Есть ли **общее решение** для задач с такой грамматической моделью.
2. Вопрос об обособлении **согласованных** определений **в постпозиции** обсуждался в недавних темах **на форуме: [1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476607/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) и [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476635/%D0%A3-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%BE%D0%BC).**  Но мне показалось, что участники **не всегда верно** понимают решение подобных задач.
3. **Чем интересна эта модель?**

**При обособлении** придаточное (предикативная конструкция) входит в состав обособленного определения (полупредикативной конструкции), то есть находится в **зависимом** положении. Получается как бы **конкуренция** двух структур при решении вопроса об обособлении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении я бы не стал ставить запятую. Существительное ***вид*** не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении. Ударение при чтении, конечно, можно сделать на этом слове, но тогда предложение интонационно поделится на три части, а это нежелательно. Самое вероятное ударение такое:

*Он сказал это с видом достаточно увер**Е**нным, чтобы кто-то стал ему возражать.*

Ударение на определениях из недавних тем, на которые вы ссылаетесь, невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. А какая разница: (1) не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении; (2) является смысловым центром высказывания. Именно эти вопросы могут быть неясными, на них и были ориентированы темы по ссылкам. И второй вопрос: почему у Лео не получалось составить предложение без обособления?

Comment: Думаю так. Смысловой центр, конечно, важен. Но **логический** смысл и грамматика не страдают без определений в этих предложенияз:  *"Нужно рассчитать количество денег";  "У них родился ребёнок"*. А *"Он сказал это с видом"* ничего не выражает.

Comment: Спасибо, но это звучит очень неопределенно, как проверка. Мне бы хотелось четко разграничить эти понятия и указать, как составлять предложения без обособления.  У придаточного сильная грамматика,  эта структура  сопротивляется  подчинению со стороны оборота (не хочет входить в его состав).

Comment: Составлять можно по-разному. *Чтобы осуществить проект, нужно рассчитать необходимое количество денег. / Нам нужно знать, сколько денег необходимо для проекта.* / И т. д. Вы были правы о лишних словах. Но в разговоре какой-то манагер вполне может сказать так, как написал Лео. Так же и здесь: *У них родился ребёнок с ВИЧ.* (ВИЧом не болеют! Это даже не обсуждается.)

Comment: Мне захотелось составить предложение без обособления. Но вскоре я поняла, что  с деньгами не получится, как ни крути. А как получится? Потом догадалась, в чем дело. И вы догадайтесь. Это не так трудно)

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю. Я с вами согласен. Плюс поставлю.

Answer (score 1):

Как составить предложение **с необособленным согласованным определением в постпозиции**

По Розенталю такие  одиночные определения не обособляются, если являются **смысловым центром высказывания** (предложения). (Ударение падает только на оборот, но не на существительное.)

**Вариант 1.** *Нужно рассчитать количество денег, **необходимое**, чтобы сделать проект.*

**Обособляется!** Но почему?  Ответ предельно лаконичный: Нет никаких оснований не ставить запятую.

Но  разве определение не является **смысловым центром** высказывания? Без него содержание   предложения **не будет выраженным.**

**Является.**  Но здесь **любое определение** подойдет, а для необособления этого нет оснований.  Два ударения, на существительном  и на определении (в конце предложения).

**Вариант 2.**   *У них родился ребёнок,  больной СПИДом.*

**Запятая ставится?**  Ставится, нет оснований не ставить. Определительный оборот обособляется по обычным правилам. Существительное **не нуждается** в этом определении, а оно само смысловым центром не является.

**Но тут же главное — болезнь!**    Да, главное.  Но опять же обособленное определение тоже подойдет.  Ставится два ударения, на существительном и определении.

**Вариант 3.**   *Он сказал это **с видом достаточно уверенным,** чтобы кто-то стал ему возражать.*

А вот здесь получилось **не обособить.**   Почему?  Здесь **синтаксически неделимое СОЧЕТАНИЕ**: главное слово (существительное)  не имеет смысла без определения.

Синтаксическая неделимость большинства словосочетаний объясняется **семантической недостаточностью** их главного слова, например: человек, люди, мужчина, женщина, вещь,
дело, занятие, вопрос, место, время и др. В их содержании (весьма отвлеченном) отсутствует характеризующая предмет информация.

**ВЫВОД**

Надо различать **варианты:**

1. Без определения  предложение  **не передает нужный смысл** (определение как смысл **ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ**). Подойдет любое определение, в том числе обособленное.
2. Определение является **смысловым центром СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЯ** сущ. + прилагательное, так что его нельзя обособить.

Но неужели можно составить предложение без обособления только для **отвлеченных существительных?** Нет, можно и для других. **Попробуйте…**  Это будет **четвертый вариант.**